# Rewrite of binomial expression

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

During a derivation of handed out lecture notes they have the following 
$$\sum_{m \geq 0}\left(\begin{array}{l}
{n} \\
{m}
\end{array}\right)(2 m+1) = 2 \sum_{m \geq 0}\left(\begin{array}{c}
{n} \\
{m}
\end{array}\right) m+2^{n}$$

But i cant quite see why this is correct. I see how you might rewrite it as 
$$2 \sum_{m \geq 0}\left(\begin{array}{c}
{n} \\
{m}
\end{array}\right) m+\left(\begin{array}{c}
{n} \\
{m}
\end{array}\right)$$
But then the binomial coefficient would have to be $2^n$.
Which only makes sense if they mean that 
$$\sum_{m \geq 0}\left(\begin{array}{l}
{n} \\
{m}
\end{array}\right)(2 m+1) = 2 \sum_{m \geq 0}\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}
{n} \\
{m}
\end{array}\right) m\right)+2^{n}$$
What am i missing here?

Comment: When you split up the sum, you get $\sum_{m \geq 0}\binom{n}{m}$, not $\binom{n}{m}$ (note that in the stated result, the $2^n$ is not being summed over $m$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{m = 0}^n \binom{n}{m}$ is indeed equal to $2^n$. This can be seen by considering $2^n = (1+1)^n$ and then using the binomial theorem.